# sed command to take variable

Tags: shell, unix, sed, aix

I have file File1.txt in which i have to replace a text using sed command

File1.txt contents

```
EURAMOUNTTOBEREPLACED
```

I have a AIX shell script for replacing the text AMOUNTTOBEREPLACED

Contents of the shell script

```
sum=27
sed 's/AMOUNTTOBEREPLACED/"$sum"/g'  File1.txt >> temp
mv temp FileNew.txt
```

After executing the script, the contents of FileNew.txt is as below

```
EUR"$sum"
```

But Expected output should be

```
EUR27
```

Please help how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below sed command instead:

```
sed -e "s/AMOUNTTOBEREPLACED/\"${sum}\"/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the one you want is like this:

```
sed 's/AMOUNTTOBEREPLACED/'$sum'/g' File1.txt >> temp
```

Basically single qouting takes the string to sed and skips shell which is wrong. You want the shell to interpret the variable so thats what i did. And further if you happen to have gnu version of sed. Then you can do

```
sed -i 's/AMOUNTTOBEREPLACED/'$sum'/g' File1.txt
```

which compressed these two statement in your code to one in above:

```
sed 's/AMOUNTTOBEREPLACED/'$sum'/g'  File1.txt >> temp
mv temp FileNew.txt
```

Comment: @user1929905 I corrected the double qoute. Incoginto has also explained in his answer.